# SwiftUI - Add description under a toggle switch that is part of a list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to add a description below a list item, similar to Apple-like lists.

I'm using Xcode 11 for iOS 13.2

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Account information")){
            Text(User.email)
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Toggle("Daily Digest", isOn: $dailyDigest)
                    Text("Receive a daily email with the events occurring on that day").font(.system(size: 10))
            }
        }
    }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle()).navigationBarTitle("Settings")
}
```

The description under the toggle switch, I wish it look like this:

[image: this]

instead of

[image: that]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `footer`:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Account information"),
                footer: Text("Receive a daily email with the events occurring on that day")) { // <- add footer
            Text("asd")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Toggle("Daily Digest", isOn: $dailyDigest)
            }
        }
    }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle()).navigationBarTitle("Settings")
}
```

Comment: `footer` is what I was looking for. Thank you very much :)